# Get list of users from OpenFire server

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I'm currently trying to make a Strophe based javascript script to get the list of available users in an OpenFire server (live refreshing needed). I don't care if I have to create a group, room or whatever it's called (anyway, the server will be running for only a small group of users, everyone connected to eachother), but I want to be able to make the server give such a list.
How can I do this? I've read that I need to use muc extension, but I can't seem to find it anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved! I had to add the users I was working with to a group and eachtime a user leaves or enters the room OpenFire notifies the other users of the room with a presence stanza wrapped inside a body tag most of the times. This makes Strophe to not identify those presence stanzas very well, so I had to overwrite the xmlInput function from the Strophe connection to get every single xml stanza that I get from the server.

```js
conn.xmlInput = onXmlInput;
function onXmlInput(data) {
    Strophe.forEachChild(data, "presence", function(child) {
        var from = child.getAttribute('from');
        from = from.substring(0, from.indexOf('@'));
        //'type' will contain "unavailable" when offline and no attribute 'type' when online
        if (!child.hasAttribute('type')) {
            addUser(from);
        } else {                    
            deleteUser(from);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi , you are creating a group and from that you are getting online users but is this having limitation for 30 user ?

Comment: I haven't had any trouble with limitations since I've not worked with large amounts of users... maybe you could post a question in a separate thread about this ;)

Comment: what inside adduser and deleteuser method?

Comment: @ButaniVijay `addUser` and `deleteUser` are your custom methods to execute when a new user joins or disconnects from the server. In my case, I added and removed them from a list of connected users. Here's my `addUser` method: `$("select#recepients").append("<option id="+from+">"+from+"</option>")`